# Laravel mail queue not posting to mailtrap

Tags: php, laravel-5, queue, laravel-artisan

I've been trying to make Laravel's Queuing work for hours and to no avail I have not Idea what's going on; I think the queues are working since they are posting to the database but what I don't understand is why aren't they executing and posting to mailtrap.

I've set my `.env` file to `database`

`QUEUE_DRIVER=database`

My controller:

```
$mailQueue  =   (new SendNotification($contact))
                     ->delay(5);

dispatch($mailQueue);
```

My Send Notification Job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

use Mail;
use App\Mail\Notification;

class SendNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $contact;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($contact)
    {
        $this->contact  =   $contact;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $notification   =   (new Notification($contact));

        Mail::to('email')
                ->queue($notification);
    }
}
```

Finally, my Mailable:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Notification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    protected $contact;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($contact)
    {
        $this->contact  =   $contact;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        return $this->view('mail.notify')
                    ->with([
                        'notifyName'    =>   $this->request->name,
                        'notifySubject' =>   $this->request->subject
                    ]);
    }
}
```

Pretty basic really, but I don't understand why its not posting or sending to Mail trap; although my `Jobs` table is filled with Queues that won't post.

Has anyone ever had this problem? if so anyone know what the solution is - I tried `php artisan queue:work` and `php artisan queue:listen` but they don't post anything out on terminal.

UPDATE:
I tried `php artisan queue:work --queue=high, emails` the output was

`Processing: App\Mail\Notification`

but it still didn't send any mail to Mailtrap.

Comment: Did you check your log for errors? `./storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you have a `public function via()` set in your Notification. You need to specify how you want the notification to be delivered.

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}
```

Also Notifications normally extend `Illuminate\Notifications\Notification`.

Nevermind looks like you aren't using the built in notification system. My guess is the problem is with this:

```
$mailQueue  =   (new SendNotification($contact))
                     ->delay(5);
```

If you look in the documentation it passes a Carbon object into the delay.

```
$job = (new ProcessPodcast($podcast))
  ->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10));
```

Comment: I tried that @Pitchinnate but it's still not working - I even made a separate project just to test out queuing but all its doing is `processing` and never sending - I'm guessing it failed to post but I don't know why. I've also made another mailable to send mail to a different user after the queuing finishes but the queue adds to the jobs database but never post while the other none queued mail is sent.

Comment: NOTE: I'm using a mailable class instead of a notification class since it's easier, in a way.

I've also discovered that my `SendNotification` class had been processed but the Mailiable class is still processing I'm guessing that's where the fail state is occuring.

`[2017-08-29 02:16:28] Processing: App\Jobs\SendNotification`

`[2017-08-29 02:16:28] Processed:  App\Jobs\SendNotification`

`[2017-08-29 02:16:28] Processing: App\Mail\Notification`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but what I tried to debug the error messages was using `php artisan queue:listen --tries=3` it posted to failed after the third attempt and output a specific error log!